# RSA attack, 1 message with different keys?

Tags: rsa

There is 1 message, it is encrypted with 6 different keys, each has E = 5.
I tried various attacks, but they do not seem to work.

Is it possible to receive a private key / encrypted message? Is it safe to use a small E?

Comment: The question's first paragraph is a duplicate (assuming textbook RSA or a common padding is used). The rest seems to ask something different (with little details). It is best to ask a single thing per question (or only closely related ones).